# JPA Spring MVC configuration

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-mvc, persistence.xml

I am trying to connect to MySQL db using JPA and Spring. I am new to Spring.

I have added this to my config file where all the beans are defined:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myEmf" jndi-name="hello-world"/>

<bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="myEmf"/>
   <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
   <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
</property>
</bean>
```

Also Here is my persistence.xml, my persistence unit name is "hello-world".

```
<persistence-unit name="hello-world" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

When I try to instantiate the object, it throws me error.

Thanks,
Sara.

Update, error:

> 2012/08/28 23-25-56,993:8a4cd57fec4d0:ERR:ERROR[Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(1) A pseudo attribute name is expected.] 2012-08-28
>   23:25:56,994 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/sara].[jsp]:704]
>   : Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to configure
>   EntityManagerFactory  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:265)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:125)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
>     at com.paypal.sara.sara.web.sample.mvc.Main.getPoints(Main.java:21)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
>   org.apache.commons.el.ArraySuffix.evaluate(ArraySuffix.java:314)  at
>   org.apache.commons.el.ComplexValue.evaluate(ComplexValue.java:145)    at
>   org.apache.commons.el.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.el.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:190)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was! Such a simple one but took my time.

I had `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">` instead I should have had `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

Thanks for your time.